# Page redirection via htaccess,php,javascript,etc

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, server-side

I would like to ask one question:

How do i redirect requests to http://sub.example.com or http://sub.example.com to

http://sub.example.com/index.php? And I'm not asking about setting index.php as the DirectoryIndex, im asking to physically redirect the server to http://sub.example.com/index.php instead of just executing index.php with sub.example.com at the address bar. Are there any .htaccess or php serverside solutions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with htaccess for example

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

rewrites everything which is not a physical file or folder to the index.php

to do a hard redirect from / to /index.php do

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://sub.exmaple.com/index.php
```

Comment: have you cofigured your webserver/virtualhost properly to allow .htaccess to overwrite values?

Comment: yes i have, going to sub.example.com just gives sub.example.com?

Comment: mod rewrite doesn't to redirects, but rewrites the request internally. so if you call sub.example.com it internally calls the index.php, also if you call sub.exmaple.com/foo/bar/baz it calls the index.php if the folder does not exist.

Comment: Ok, i require a hard reset because i use jquery mobile (changepage function) for the mobile version of my site. going to sub.example.com,then sub.example.com/manage.php then back to sub.example.com causes the pagebeforeshow events of the latter to be unfired while going to sub.example.com/index.php works fine